# network Authentication and website Authentication using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am trying to create a application that will consume RSS data using .NET Framework. The RSS site requires User name and Password to start with.
and Am running this application from within my work place which requires NTLM authentication to connect to internet.

Following is the code that i am trying to use

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("SITEUSERNAME", "SITEPASSWORD");
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(new Uri(RSSFeed), "Basic", nc);
cache.Add(new Uri(RSSFeed), "Ntlm", new NetworkCredential("USERNAME","PASSWORD","DOAMIN"));
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RSSFeed);
myHttpWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = cache;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

i get 407 error and if i simply use CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials i get 401 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code works, then your original code above was wrong. You should set

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

and

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("SITEUSERNAME", "SITEPASSWORD");
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(new Uri(RSSFeed), "Basic", nc);
cache.Add(new Uri(RSSFeed), "Ntlm", new NetworkCredential("USERNAME","PASSWORD","DOAMIN"));
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RSSFeed);
myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = cache;
```

In other words, you had exchanged credentials for the proxy and the destination server.

Answer (score 3):

solved the issue by using following code

```
 string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("UserName" + ":" + "Password"));
 StringBuilder outputData = new StringBuilder();
 HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RSSFeed);
 myHttpWebRequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
 myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
 HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
 Stream streamResponse = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
```