# HTTP basic authentication not working with WebBrowser.Navigate

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, webbrowser-control

I'm using a WebBrowser control to post to a URL which is password protected. I'm supplying the authorization header but internet explorer still shows the user password popup when it is opened.

`webBrowser.Navigate(url, "_blank", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Environment.NewLine + "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userpassword)) + Environment.NewLine);`

What's more peculiar here is that it doesn't work even if you supply the correct credentials there when the browser window is opened. The popup keeps reappearing.

And it works if I remove the header from above call and supply correct credentials in internet explorer popup window.

Comment: try navigating to username:password@url

Comment: @VladL a COM exception is thrown at runtime

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583052/network-authentication-and-website-authentication-using-httpwebrequest

Comment: @Mukund_Roy my question is specific to WebBrowser.Navigate not with HttpWebRequest

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but is userpassword username:password?

Comment: are you sure that userpassword must be passed as header and not as part of POST data?

Comment: @C.M. Yes, it is username:password

Comment: @VladL Yes, because it is http authentication put by server using .htaccess