# Passing credentials when using PrintServer

Tags: c#, printing, networkcredentials

I'm using print server:

```
PrintServer myPrintServer = new PrintServer(@"\\printsrv");
```

but I get exception:

> An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: The user name or password is incorrect.

How can I pass username and password?

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168571/run-code-as-a-different-user-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have the network credentials cached for that server. I think the easiest way is to start a `net use` command from code:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "use \\printsrv password /user:domain\username";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

After that the `PrintServer` class should be able to connect. You could also try these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583052/network-authentication-and-website-authentication-using-httpwebrequest) to get the credentials cached beforehand.